Immersions are local diffeomorphisms
I am trying to understand the proof why the the image of an immersion and differentiable map between manifolds $f:M \to N$ is a submanifold. I am following the book of Guillemin, Differential Topology (https://www.cimat.mx/~gil/docencia/2020/topologia_diferencial/%5BGuillemin,Pollack%5DDifferential_Topology(1974).pdf).
And there is one point I didn't quite get. On p. 16 it says that by the local immersion theorem any small neighbourhood of a point $x \in M$ is mapped diffeomorphically onto its image $f(W)$.
So I know that the local immersion theorem says that for suitable coordinates f looks like the canonical immersion  (here $m \leq n$):
$$
\iota: \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n, (x_1,...,x_m) \mapsto (x_1,...,x_m,0,...,0)
$$
Hence, the last n-m components play no important role. I first thought I could use the local inverse theorem to show that f is locally diffeomorphic but this requires the domain and image to have the same dimension. Even if the image looks like it is m-dimensional, for the local inverse theorem to apply f(M) has to be a manifold which is what has to be shown.

I'm not quite sure what your question is. Are you trying to find out how to construct a chart?

Your last several sentences seem all jumbled. It's not clear whether you are trying to prove the local immersion theorem or to apply it. I would have thought you were trying to apply it, but then your sentence "I first thought..." makes it seem you are trying to prove it.

I want to know why f is a local diffeomorphism onto its image. The local inverse theorem was the first tool that came to my mind. Thanks for your criticism. I hope my edit makes it clearer

Recall the definition of differentiability on manifolds.

A map $f:M \rightarrow N$ between differentiable manifolds is called differentiable if, for all compatible charts $(U,\phi) \in A_M$, (V,$\psi)\in A_N$, $$\psi \circ f \circ \phi^{-1}$$ is a differentiable function between Euclidean spaces (here $A_N,A_M$ are the respective atlases).

Because an atlas is a maximal collection of such compatible charts, it suffices to check that $f$ is a diffeomorphism by finding charts in which that composition is a diffeomorphism.
This is precisely how the local immersion theorem is being applied. The canonical immersion is a diffeomorphism onto its image. Then (by the theorem) you have found charts in which $f$ is a (local) diffeomorphism; hence, by definition, $f$ is a local diffeomorphism.
